# Filter a list of elements for membership in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I'm using Python+Pymongo (though this question could apply in any language) and I have a list of emails in Python, `emails=['email1@example.com','email2@example.com',...]` and I have a collection in MongoDB with a bunch of documents. Each document in MongoDB has an `email` field.  What is the most efficient (and elegant) way to filter the Python list, so when I'm done it only contains emails which are present in one of the `email` fields in MongoDB?

INPUT: `emails=['email1@example.com','email2@example.com',...]`

OUTPUT: `filteredEmails=[ <sublist of 'emails' with only elements present in MongoDB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `email` field is indexed, just look-up each value. That should be fast enough.

```
common_emails = [ email for email in emails if coll.find_one({ 'email': email }) ]
```

If the collection is small, or you don't want to index the `email` field, doing the intersection in-memory would prove faster:

```
db_emails = [ doc['email'] for doc in coll.find({}, projection = {'email':1, '_id':0}) if doc ]
common_emails = set(emails) & set(db_emails)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
> db.people.insert({name:"Fred",email:"fred@email.com"})
> db.people.insert({name:"Derf",email:"derf@email.com"})
> db.people.insert({name:"Bob",email:"bob@email.com"})
>
>
> emails = ["derf@email.com", "bob@email.com"]
[ "derf@email.com", "bob@email.com" ]
> db.people.find({email:{$in: emails}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53a1f4b44336adbf6340356a"), "name" : "Derf", "email" : "derf@email.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53a1f4bb4336adbf6340356b"), "name" : "Bob", "email" : "bob@email.com" }
```

Simply use `.find()` with the `$in` operator to find all documents whose email is in the email list.

Comment: How efficient is this operation?  Does the time complexity grow with the length of the email list?  What if the list is really long?